# IntelliJ plugin: Editing Run Configuration settings programmatically and/or creating from context

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, mocha.js

Posted to the IntelliJ community as well.

What I want to do, in short, is create an instance of a Run Configuration (not one of my own creation, specifically Mocha) programmatically based on an EditorPopupMenu action. (For context, later on I want to be able to add a before run action, and trigger it to run).

I have created an empty configuration via

```
ConfigurationType type = ConfigurationTypeUtil.findConfigurationType("mocha-javascript-test-runner");
ConfigurationFactory[] factories = type.getConfigurationFactories();
RunnerAndConfigurationSettings racs = runManager.createConfiguration("testConfig", factories[0]);
```

but I'm unsure how to fill out the settings fields that you normally do via the UI. I have seen the SettingsEditor page referenced by the sdk docs, but that seems to be UI only. The rest of the documentation for run configurations focuses on making your own, not manipulating existing ones programmatically.

I can see in the debugger that a MochaRunSettings object exists with all the fields I'm after but I don't see a method to access it. I also don't know how to create one manually, or turn it into a RunnerAndConfigurationSettings object if I could make it.

Similarly almost all of what I want to set up I think could be done using ConfigurationContext similar to clicking the run button in the gutter. I've done

```
ConfigurationContext cc = new ConfigurationContext(e.getData(LangDataKeys.PSI_ELEMENT));
```

but that doesn't seem to have much info when I check it in the debugger, and I'm not sure what method I need to turn it into an actual RunnerAndConfigurationSettings object.

Maybe I'm also just taking a completely wrong approach?

Thanks for any tips anyone has.

Bonus question: How do you programmatically trigger a RunnerAndConfigurationSettings config to actually run as if you clicked it/did Shift+F10?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development would be the best place for such quesrions.

Comment: As I said at the top I posted it there too and didn't get a response yet, so thought I might as well post it here too

Answer (score 0):

Okay I kind of got this working. Here's what was needed:

```
ConfigurationType type = ConfigurationTypeUtil.findConfigurationType("mocha-javascript-test-runner");

MapDataContext dataContext = new MapDataContext();
dataContext.put(CommonDataKeys.PROJECT, project);
dataContext.put(Location.DATA_KEY, PsiLocation.fromPsiElement(e.getData(LangDataKeys.PSI_ELEMENT)));

List<RunConfigurationProducer<?>> runConfProds = RunConfigurationProducer.getProducers(project);
RunConfigurationProducer runConfProd = null;
// I got the producer above by checking entries in 'runConfProds' against 'type'
// Unfortunately it gets two matches, so it's a bit scuffed right now. Probably better way to do this.

ConfigurationContext configurationContext = ConfigurationContext.getFromContext(dataContext);
ConfigurationFromContext configurationFromContext = runConfProd.createConfigurationFromContext(configurationContext);

RunnerAndConfigurationSettings runnerAndConfigurationSettings = configurationFromContext.getConfigurationSettings();
Executor executor = DefaultRunExecutor.getRunExecutorInstance();
ExecutionUtil.runConfiguration(runnerAndConfigurationSettings, executor);
```